# SQL Creating table Employee Department Grade

Tags: sql-server

create database staff_management;

use staff_management;

create table Employee 
(
    eID int(100) NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    eName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Job text NOT NULL, 
    Salary int(100) NOT NULL,
    Comm int(100),
    hDate date NOT NULL, 
    dID int(10) NOT NULL,

```
constraint emp_pk primary key (eID)
```

);
alter table Employee IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY=1001;

alter table Employee 
add column Mgr int(100) after eName;

insert into Employee(eName,Mgr,  Job, Salary, Comm, hDate, dID)
values( "ken Adams", 1004, "Salesman", 70000, 20000, "2008-04-12", 1),
("Ru Jones", 1004, "Salesman", 65000, 15000, "2010-01-18", 1),
( "Dhal Sim", 1006, "Accountant", 88000, NULL, "2001-03-07", 2),
( "Ellen Honda", 1006, "Manager", 118000, NULL, "2001-03-17", 1),
( "Mike Bal", 1006, "Receptionist", 68000, NULL, "2006-06-21", 3),
( "Martin Bison",NULL, "CEO", 210000, NULL, "2010-07-12", 3),
( "Shen Li", 1004, "Salesman", 86000, 18000, "2014-09-18", 1),
( "Zang Ross", 1004, "Salesman", 65000, 10000, "2017-02-02", 1),
( "Sagar Kahn", 1004, "Salesman", 70000, 15000, "2016-03-01", 1);

alter table Employee
add constraint emp_mgr_fk foreign key (Mgr) references Employee(eID) on update cascade on delete set NULL;

create table Department
(
    dID int(10) NOT NULL unique IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    dName varchar(255) not null,
    Address text, 
    phone text,

```
constraint d_pk primary key (dID)
```

);

alter table Employee
add constraint emp_d_fk
foreign key (dID) references Department(dID);

create table Grade
(
    gID char(10) not null unique,
    MinSal int(100), 
    MaxSal int(100),
    Leavee int(10),

```
constraint g_pk primary key (gID)
```

);

INSERT INTO Grade (gID, MinSal, MaxSal, Leavee)
VALUES ('A', NULL, 60000, 20),
('B', 60000, 80000, 20),
('C', 80000, 100000, 20),
('D', 100000, 120000, 25), 
('E', 120000, NULL, 30);

select * from Grade;

insert into Department (dName, Address, phone)
values("Sales", "Sydney", "0425 198 053"),
("Accounts", "Melbourne", "0429 198 955"),
("Admin", "Melbourne", "0428 198 758"),
("Marketing", "Sydney", "0427 198 757");

select * from Department;

I'm issue with my code

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IDENTITY'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'column'.

Comment: Which database engine are you using?

Comment: The data type `text` has been deprecated of nearly 15 years. Use `varchar(MAX)` instead and only when you need over 8000 characters. It seems `varchar(n)` is more appropriate for address and phone.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for **SQL Server** is **NOT** `auto_increment` - you need to use an `INT IDENTITY` column instead. And also: in T-SQL an `INT` is an `INT` is an `INT` - no "precision" can be defined):

Instead of this:

```
create table Employee 
(
    eID int(100) NOT NULL auto_increment,
```

use this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Employee 
(
    eID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is posted under SQL-Server which is Microsoft not MySQL but your syntax appears to be for MySQL.

If you are running MSSQL the code below will work but you need to look at your foreign keys as you are trying to make a foreign key for a column on the same table. Normally when a key is introduced it is in relation to another table. I.E.the FK on Grade references the PK on Employee.

```
create database staff_management; 

use staff_management;

create table Employee 
(
    eID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    eName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Job text NOT NULL, 
    Salary int NOT NULL,
    Comm int,
    hDate date NOT NULL, 
    dID int NOT NULL,
);

alter table Employee 
add  Mgr int;

insert into Employee(eName,Mgr,  Job, Salary, Comm, hDate, dID)
values ('ken Adams', 1004, 'Salesman', 70000, 20000, '2008-04-12', 1),
       ('Ru Jones', 1004, 'Salesman', 65000, 15000, '2010-01-18', 1),
       ('Dhal Sim', 1006, 'Accountant', 88000, NULL, '2001-03-07', 2),
       ('Ellen Honda', 1006, 'Manager', 118000, NULL, '2001-03-17', 1),
       ('Mike Bal', 1006, 'Receptionist', 68000, NULL, '2006-06-21', 3),
       ('Martin Bison',NULL, 'CEO', 210000, NULL, '2010-07-12', 3),
       ('Shen Li', 1004, 'Salesman', 86000, 18000, '2014-09-18', 1),
       ('Zang Ross', 1004, 'Salesman', 65000, 10000, '2017-02-02', 1),
       ('Sagar Kahn', 1004, 'Salesman', 70000, 15000, '2016-03-01', 1);


--alter table Employee
--add constraint emp_mgr_fk 
--    foreign key (Mgr) references Employee(eID) 
--    on update cascade on delete set NULL;

create table Department
(
    dID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    dName varchar(255) not null,
    Address text, 
    phone text,
);

--alter table Employee
--add constraint emp_d_fk
--foreign key (dID) references Department(dID);


create table Grade
(
    gID char(10) not null unique,
    MinSal int, 
    MaxSal int,
    Leavee int,

    constraint g_pk primary key (gID)
);


INSERT INTO Grade (gID, MinSal, MaxSal, Leavee)
VALUES ('A', NULL, 60000, 20),
       ('B', 60000, 80000, 20),
       ('C', 80000, 100000, 20),
       ('D', 100000, 120000, 25), 
       ('E', 120000, NULL, 30);

select * from Grade;


insert into Department (dName, Address, phone)
values ('Sales', 'Sydney', '0425 198 053'),
       ('Accounts', 'Melbourne', '0429 198 955'),
       ('Admin', 'Melbourne', '0428 198 758'),
       ('Marketing', 'Sydney', '0427 198 757');

select * from Department;
```

Comment: i did try something different with solution and now i receiving this error. I just update the with new information